# Automation Test - Android adb connect to UC browser

Tags: javascript, android, automation, adb, uc-browser

I'm working on E2E automation testing on opening a local website in different mobile browsers. I'm using [testcafe](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe) automation tool and it will generate a testing url with all automated cursor moves, clicks and screenshots. It works very well on desktop browsers and I would like to push the url to android devices.

I'm using following command to open android browsers, it works in many common browsers but not UC browser. In UC browser it only opens the app but not the specific url.

`adb shell am start -n com.UCMobile/com.uc.browser.InnerUCMobile -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d http://google.com`

How can I use adb tool to open UC browser with a specific url?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
adb shell am start  -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d "http://google.com" com.UCMobile.intl
```

In my country the package name of the UC Browser is com.UCMobile.intl.
Replace it with the package name of your browser.

[More Info](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/deep-linking)

Comment: Many many thanks. It works perfectly. Although to me the package name is com.UCMobile. Thanks again!